# How to return sorted elements by name to previous array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two arrays. Array, where elements should be returned back, is set with pagination so 30 elements are displayed, and there are 5 pages. The problem is when I push elements to that array if their first position was on page 2 of pagination when I return them they are on page 1 until I refresh the whole page. What is good practice for this case?
This is my code for removing(pushing back) these elements:

```
function removeAll() {  
        if(vm.rationList.length > 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.rationList.length; i++) {
            vm.feeds.push(vm.rationList[i])
            }
        vm.rationList = []
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split the array into chunks, then return the chunks. Pushing back and removing array seems very unnecessary.

```js
function chunk(list, chunkSize) {
 return new Array(Math.ceil(list.length / chunkSize)).fill().map(_ => list.splice(0,chunkSize))
}

const arr = new Array(150).fill();

const chunked = chunk(arr, 30);
console.log(chunked.length, chunked.map(({length}) => length));


// get 3rd page

console.log(chunked[2]);
```